# Why does the opcode for MOV from a segment register not have its low bit set? It's not 8-bit operand-size, so the W bit should be set

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, mov, instruction-encoding

I am having a problem where I can't understand the opcode of this instruction **MOV BX,CS** like the first byte is 10001100 where the first 6 bit represents the opcode then the direction 1 bit follows then the W. So here is my doubt why in the opcode it is 100011 and not 100010 and in the W cell why there is 0 and not 1 like for what purpose or there is some condition that I should be careful for.

[image: This is the instruction representation]

I would really appreciate if someone can give me a detailed answer.

When I tried to solve with more than 1 method I just can't get the solution that is shown in the pic above and I watched a lot of videos but didn't find an answer that clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some opcodes don't follow that pattern, including the ones for `mov` to/from segment registers.  There's no 8-bit version of those instructions, so the low bit does not represent Width = 8 vs. 16-bit.

The low 2 bits being Direction and Width is not universal, it's just a pattern that exists in most normal ALU opcodes that come in pairs for 8-bit and 16/32/64-bit operand-size<sup>1</sup>, like `and`, `add`, `cmp`, etc. which have both directions, immediate forms with both `imm16` and sign-extended `imm8` for 16-bit operand-size, and `al, imm8` / `ax, imm16` short encodings with no ModRM.  Also ones like `shr` that don't have both directions, but do have both sizes.

Even `mov` for non segment registers has some special forms, with a `mov reg, imm` form with the register number as the low 3 bits of the opcode, instead of direction or width.  And no `mov r/m16, sign_extended_imm8` because 8086 had no use for that.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov shows the various mov opcodes.)

---

The `mov r/m, Sreg` opcode you're looking at is 8C.  The four opcodes with different values of its low 2 bits include `mov Sreg, r/m`, but also two unrelated opcodes that have the low bit set, and all exist only in forms with 16-bit operand-size so it doesn't really mean W for any of them.  Although it does work for LEA and `pop`.

- `8C` is `mov r/m, Sreg`, the opcode you're asking about.
- `8D` is `lea`
- `8E` is `mov Sreg, r/m` (which does exist with the d bit set, and works with any segment reg other than CS in the /r field of ModRM.  Encoding it with a CS destination is possible, but it will raise a #UD exception on CPUs after 8086.  8086 didn't have an illegal-instruction exception; every bit-pattern ran as something.  Some 8086 models even ran mov to CS as a jump.)
- `8F` is `pop r/m`.

See http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x8C for list of instructions by opcode.  There are many other exceptions to the pattern, like `cli` and `sti` being FA and FB respectively.

---

Footnote 1: With 16/32/64-bit operand-size all having the same opcode.  The default is implied by the current mode.  A `66h` prefix sets the opposite of 16 or 32-bit, or a REX.W prefix selects 64-bit.

There wasn't room for new opcodes when 386 and AMD64 were being designed, so they went with prefixes instead.